# Set the width of bar chart in telerik chart using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik, bar-chart

How to Set the width of bar chart in telerik chart using xamarin.forms that should overwrite the default width of the bar chart.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on the question to enable people to help you. What have you already tried? What isn't working when you tried it and why did it not work? Also the Telerik support forum may be a better place to put this question if it's not a problem in Xamarin Forms itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below link for your solution.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-barseries